# No connection to Elasticsearch with Python on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, elasticsearch, connection

I have written a Python script that does some search stuff using an Elasticsearch server, both running on the same machine.

Everything works well on my Windows 10 desktop, but the same script ist not able to connect to Elasticsearch on my Windows 11 laptop.

I have tried:

- different versions of Elasticsearch including the newest 8.10.4 and the slightly older version from my Windows 10 desktop
- try to login to Elasticsearch using a browser or kibana (no problem)
- disable Windows 11 firewall for a short time (no effect)
- try 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost'

Nothing works.

This is the login-procedure:

```
def connect_to_elastic() -> Elasticsearch:
    es = Elasticsearch(
        f"https://localhost:9200",
        ssl_assert_fingerprint="...",        
        basic_auth=("username", 'password'))
    
    if es.ping():
        print('Connected to Elasticsearch cluster')
        connections.add_connection('default', es)
        return es
    else:
        print('ping did not work')

es = connect_to_elastic()
```

The result is always 'ping did not work'...

Whenever I try the script, Elasticsearch is creating a Warning:

```
[2023-11-03T18:05:38,798][WARN ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [mycomputer] caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/localhost:9200, remoteAddress=/localhost:57323}java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:46)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:294)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:269)
```

Does anybody know what I could do? Is this a Windows 11 topic or ist the Laptop maybe only missing a Python library or something completly different?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: My best guess is your assert of the fingerprint is causing the connection to close when it does not match the Fingerprint for the ssl cert you are getting from elastic when you connect.   try removing that parameter and see if it works better.